# what are benefits of using Encoding in binary reader and writer C#?

Tags: c#

i am learning binary reader and writer libraries

i want to know what the importance of Encoding as parameter while

making a new object of binary reader or writer

I tried to do many things like make this code

```
FileStream fs = new FileStream("hello.bin", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.None);

        BinaryWriter ws = new BinaryWriter(fs, Encoding.UTF8);

        ws.Write("Hello world ");


        using (BinaryReader rs = new BinaryReader(fs, Encoding.ASCII))
        {
            rs.BaseStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
            string name =rs.ReadString();
            Console.WriteLine(name);
        }


            Console.ReadKey();
```

but the same result " hello world " is output even if i have changed the encoding

in binary reader to any thing like utf-7 , ascii

Thanks :)

Comment: You don't see the difference because "Hello world " contains characters that are available in both character sets.

Comment: Worth reading: [The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2003/10/08/the-absolute-minimum-every-software-developer-absolutely-positively-must-know-about-unicode-and-character-sets-no-excuses/)

Comment: Binary data you should NEVER use encoding because it WILL corrupt the data.  Even UTF8 will change value of 0x80.

Comment: @jdweng Only if you for some reason write it as strings. BinaryWriter/Reader won’t use encoding for anything else than strings.

Comment: @ Sami Kuhmonen : I'm not sure.  Seen too many issues to be 100% sure that encoding won't cause issues with Binary Writer/Reader.  Most binary data contains ASCII strings and include a CRC.  So if strings get changed that the CRC will fail.

Comment: @jdweng. With 'corrupt' you mean the representation in memory is not the same as in the stream. This is correct, but It's not a problem. The intention is to save disk-space, by converting a two-byte-per character string , into a one-byte-per character-string; with the assumptions, most characters are ASCII. This is completly transparent if you do it on read and write; nothing will be corrupted.

Comment: @Holger : Where are your assumption coming from?  You are making an assumption that the OP wants to save space.  A string in c# is a class with two bytes and a private property indicating if each the character is one or two bytes.  To assume a string is only one bytes is a bad assumption.  If you only want one byte strings the use byte[] (terminated with '\0') and do the conversion.

Comment: @jdweng. There is no assumption and there is nothing C# related. This is the idea, the meaning of encoding. If you don't want to do any encoding, you have to tell this the streamwriter, by setting encoding to BigEndianUnicode, which still takes care of, which byte of a character is written first. If you want to save an 'A' you still have to say, if you first write the byte 0 or the byte 65. It's not important what you do, but you have to ensure you read it in the same order. This behaviour is called 'encoding'. 
In a stream, there is no requirement, each character must have same # of bytes.

Comment: Just do not put any encoding into the stream writer and it will work.   As I SAID DO NOT EVER USE ENCODING WITH BINARY DATA.  IT WILL CORRUPT DATA.  it is much easier to follow my one rule than to make a lot of exceptions that can cause issues.

Comment: @jdweng. It is not possible to use 'no encoding'. You have to define how a string is written to a stream. You do not even explain, what kind of irreversible corruption you expect. What is the corruption in storing an 'A' in the sequence 0-65, or 65-0 or just storing a 65. Everything is fine, as long as you know how to read it. There is never a loss, you always can reproduce your 16-bit 65.

Comment: @ Holger : Isn't it just better to NOT USE ENCODING.  You are trying to come up with a bunch of rules when to use encoding instead of just not using encoding.  Not using encoding will always work.  Your method can fail.

Comment: @jdweng. There is no such option. What you say is "Isn't it better to write a string, without knowing how to write a string". It's impossible. You also have to define how you encode the length, either you zero-terminate the string, or you prepend the length. There are many options, but saying "do not choose any option"  is the only thing you cannot do.

Comment: Where does the OP say anything about a string in the Title of the Posting? Why is answers referring to strings specifically when the OP asked about using BinaryReader?  Each object in a Binary file must be treated without encoding.  After reading/writing bytes you can apply encoding.  But the entire Binary File must be treated without encoding to prevent errors?

Comment: @jdweng. System.Text.Encoding class refers to string only. And the code sample refers to string only , also. You seem to have no understanding, what Encoding means. There are no objects in a binary file, there are just bytes. You have to encode your objects to bytes. For "integers" etc. it's predefined, for string you have options, and for any other class you have to do it yourself manually. You have to define how to convert an object to an array of bytes. This process is called Encoding.

Comment: I do not think you understand what a binary file looks like.  Do not assume the OPs is referring to a class that is binary serialized in Net library.  I know exactly what encoding means and have used hundreds of different binary type files and very few are encoded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case you’re writing characters that are identical in all the character sets you use. That’s why there is no difference. The characters 0-127 are the same in ASCII, UTF-8, several ISO8859 encodings etc.

Try for example to write with UTF8 encoding the string “ąęįšžå” and then read it back with ASCII. You’ll see the difference. So your reader and writer must match in general when writing data. Otherwise there may be wrong characters read, or even exceptions when characters are invalid. For example, if you write that string as ISO8859-1 and then read as UTF-8 there will be invalid code points.

Comment: It is dangerous to use encoding with binary data!!!  Do not use encoding with any binary data.

Comment: @jdweng As I already commented, BinaryReader/Writer *will not change binary data in any way* and it has encoding *always*. It only affects *strings*